# Mysql query select sum where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with 2 tables called mutaties and products

in the mutaties you have for example a product_id(which corresponds to a product id in the products database.

so we now get the current inventory using the SUM(aantal) from the mutaties database.

the product table has for each product a threshold.

What I want to do now is setup a mysql query that gets every product that is below the threshold with his current inventory.

Right now I have this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products
     , mutaties 
 WHERE SUM(aantal) < threshold
```

But I get the error invalid use of group function.

What is the best way to do this?

This is my products table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXDIF.png)

translation of the columns is id,brand,model,threshold

and this is my mutaties database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrWJ1.png)
and here is the mutaties table translation of the colums: id product_id quantity date description

Comment: _Small Point_ `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP, it is not a database!. It may sound petty but terminology can be very important when asking questions

Comment: mutaties?  is there a simple english translation?

Comment: @P.Salmon Mutations So I would guess it might be `Product Options`

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry. mutaties table has everything in it for each product that has gone in and out of the stock and how much has gone in and out. so for example product_id 1 and then 2 products went out for example and another row in the table show product_id 2 and 3 of those items came in.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: And the `GROUP BY` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like jarlh wrote in that comment, you should probably use the modern `JOIN` syntax.
Therefore, something like this should work:

```
select p.id, sum(m.aantal) as aantalsum
from products as p
join mutaties as m on (m.product_id = p.id)
group by p.id, p.threshold
having sum(m.aantal) < p.threshold
```

Things to note:

- If you have `products` without `mutaties`, they will not appear in that select. If you need those, use `left outer join` instead.
- You have `products` with a `threshold` of 0, they will probably also not appear at all.
- If you need more columns in your select list, you also need to add them to the `group by` expression

Comment: I get unkown column p.threshold altough threshold is in the products table.

Comment: @Thomas Tschernich This query is wrong. You cannot in HAVING caluse compare to p.treshold if you were not grouping by this column.

Comment: I edited the query, maybe it works now. As there were only pictures of the table structures I could not actually recreate the example.